# Lotus Notes c API Issue

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke

Folks I am having an  unbalanced the stack problem see below

DNParse FUNCTION in the C API:

```
STATUS LNPUBLIC DNParse(DWORD Flags, const char far *TemplateName,
                        const char far *InName, DN_COMPONENTS far *Comp,
                        WORD CompSize);

using FORMULAHANDLE = System.UInt32;
using NullHandle = System.Nullable;
using Status = System.UInt16;
using DBHandle = System.IntPtr;
using DHANDLE = System.IntPtr;
using NoteID = System.UInt32;
using ColHandle = System.UInt32;
using WORD = System.UInt32;
using DWORD = System.UInt32;
using NoteHandle = System.IntPtr;
using FontID = System.UInt32;

public static unsafe string GetCurrentUserCommonName()
    {
        string str = "";
        Status sts = 0;
        DWORD xDWORD = 0;
        dname.DN_COMPONENTS DNComp = new dname.DN_COMPONENTS();            
        StringBuilder szServer = new StringBuilder(0x400, 0x400);
        StringBuilder InName = new StringBuilder(0x400, 0x400);

        Initialize();
        if (m_isInitialized)
        {
            sts = nnotesDLL.SECKFMGetUserName(szServer);                
            sts = nnotesDLL.DNParse(xDWORD, null, szServer, 
                                    DNComp, (Int16)Marshal.SizeOf(DNComp));
            // return CanonName.ToString();
        }
        return str;
    }
```

And the C# version:

```
[DllImport("nnotes.dll")]
public unsafe static extern Status DNParse(DWORD Flags, string TemplateName, 
                                           StringBuilder szServer, 
                                           dname.DN_COMPONENTS DNComp,
                                           short CompSize);
DN_COMPONENTS STRUCTURE
public struct DN_COMPONENTS
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "unbalanced the stack problem".  What happens when this code runs? What do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

The error is that the native code expects the address of the struct to be passed. But your C# code is passing the struct by value. The p/invoke should look like this:

```
[DllImport("nnotes.dll")]
public static extern Status DNParse(
    DWORD Flags, 
    string TemplateName, 
    string szServer, 
    ref dname.DN_COMPONENTS DNComp,
    short CompSize
);
```

Some other points:

1. You do not need `unsafe` here. Remove it.
2. Both string parameters are passed in to the function and the buffers are not modified. That is implied by `const char*`. So marshal them as `string`.